# Influence of skolemdepth on checking formulas in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Could someone explain the influence of skolemdepth option in Alloy?

Comment: What skolemdepth option means? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This affects how is your problem encoded as a SAT instance.

As an example:

```
∀x.∃y.∀z.∃w. P
```

would get translated to (before issuing the instance to the SAT solver)

```
∀x.∀z.∃w. P[f(x)/y]
```

(where P[a/b] means b gets substituted with a in P) with depth 1 (i.e. only y is skolemized), and to

```
∀x.∀z. P[f(x)/y, g(x,z)/w]
```

with depth 2.

From [official documentation](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/gui.html):

> Skolem Depth: This controls the maximum depth of alternating
>   universal-vs-existential quantifier that we will permit when
>   generating a skolem function. If a formula exceeds this depth, we will
>   not generate a skolem function for it.